# Run Tensorflow benchmark on CPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow

How can I run [Tensorflow CNN benchmarks](https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks/tree/master/scripts/tf_cnn_benchmarks) on the CPU? Would like to compare to GPU. Thanks!

edit: For anyone else with this issue, I also had to add `--data_format=NHWC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use command line option `--device cpu`.